# NeoVim Not Using My ~/.config/nvim/init.vim File

Tags: neovim

Just installed neovim. I just created a file `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. The `init.vim` file only has one line:

```
set relativenumber
```

But then when I opened a file using the `nvim` command (in Cygwin), the relative line numbers are not on. What is going on, and how can I fix it? My version is the latest stable release.

Comment: What is the out of `:verbose set relativenumber`?

Comment: @jdhao It sets the relative line numbers correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! @jdhao meant `:verbose set relativenumber?`, which will query it. How about `:echo $MYVIMRC`, or `:e $MYVIMRC` to try to open it? The `:version` command should list the location(s) where it will look for a vimrc file... Do those give you a clue about what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't have a Neovim package, AFAIK. So that was most probably a native Windows build. In this case your config must reside in ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim.

See also `:h init.vim` for further information.

Comment: AFAIK, you can not run Windows neovim on cygwin. They are not compatible.

Comment: @jdhao Cygwin executables have standard format (PE). The only specific thing is that they are dynamically linked to POSIX runtime compat layer (cygwin1.dll) which provides transparent filename translation and a few POSIX-specific syscalls (like fork() etc.). "Under Cygwin" typically means "inside bash compiled by Cygwin tools". And naturally, bash can run any PE under Windows (Cygwin or native) provided you've typed the pathname right.

Comment: @jdhao Of course, there could be some "issues", like Windows native built console Neovim fails to run under mintty, but, at the very least, GUI works without problem.